# Authorization in Native IOS app (Swift), with/without AD Credentials

Tags: ios, swift, active-directory

I need some kind of authorization implemented in my IOS Native App (Swift).
I thought of creating an Active Directory Integration, but problem will arise when I will use the app from remote locations as in outside of the LAN. As the app won't be able to do an AD lookup (That is my understanding).

A solution could be to do VPN, but that is quite demanding of the users to require this.

Do you have any ideas on how I can have authorization which doesn't need AD-access and requires minimal user management (maintenance) when for instance people leaves and shouldn't have access anymore. 
Any suggestions or ideas is welcome.